# Battery drains very rapidly on my Microsoft Lumia 640XL. What could be the reason? (Please read details before answering)

Tags: lumia, battery, lumia-640-xl

There are no apps running in the background (I recently factory reset it, no third party apps have been installed except one or two; and I am sure they are not the ones draining battery) and I have tried replacing the battery too; but the drain is 5℅ per hour when the phone is idle. The network signal is strong all time. And the phone has Windows 10 Mobile installed since August 2017, and I never faced such issues earlier. The phone is around 2 years old and the new battery is 3 days old. What could be the reason?

Comment: Is the battery genuine? Have you checked in battery settings to see what's actually using the battery?

Comment: Yes the battery is genuine. Even the older battery (genuine) is perfectly alright, I know that. Every app that I use uses up battery, say for instance I use Calculator for 5 minutes, Whatsapp for 2 minutes (making sure that after using they do not keep running in the background) and Edge browser for 5 minutes, battery drain will be Calculator 25℅ Whatsapp 20℅ Edge 30℅